# How to set the default email account in Outlook 2000

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How do I set the default email account for a user that has 2 POP3 accounts set up in Outlook 2000 so the FROM field in each email sent appears to be sent from XYZ instead of ABC?

It should be a similar option to Outlook 2003 below. But I can't find the equivalent in Outlook 2000.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved the problem by starting over and re-creating the user's Outlook profile

Answer (score 1):

[How to Set up Outlook 2000 Accounts](http://www.comptechdoc.org/applicat/outlook/guide/outaccount.html)

You can find the button in the "Internet Accounts" dialog in the "Tools" menu -> "Accounts":

[image: Internet Accounts Dialog]

Comment: I only have "Services" available under the Tools menu, and that button doesn't appear to be listed anywhere